# Indexeddb IDBKeyRange.only is not a function

Tags: javascript, cordova, indexeddb

I'm working on a Cordova app that utilizes some Indexeddb (with a shim in place for iOS).

I'm using `IDBKeyRange` for an object store with a defined index. This works well within the Chrome browser, but has some issues on Android and iOS.

I have the following TypeScript that was inspired by [MDN's example](https://github.com/mdn/IDBKeyRange-example/blob/gh-pages/scripts/main.js):

```
var transaction = this.db.transaction(objectStoreName, "readonly");
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(objectStoreName);
var index: any = objectStore.index(indexName);
var request = index.getAll(IDBKeyRange.only(indexValue));
```

When running within Chrome on my desktop, everything is fine. When I run the same code within the compiled Android or iOS apps, I see:

```
TypeError: IDBKeyRange.only is not a function
```

I logged out the `IDBKeyRange` object and it appears to be a function itself, but this isn't helpful since it does the same within the (working as expected) browser. Chrome logs out:

```
function IDBKeyRange()
```

My first attempt to solve the issue was to more closely follow MDN's example and do something like:

```
 window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;
```

But the same behavior occured. Any suggestions?

**Update:**

I've attempted this on 2 different Android Galaxy Tab As. Both with the same model number and Android Version (5.0.2). This works on one device but not the other (wut). Same code, same data, same build process.

And with further digging, it appears that an `index.getAll is not a function` error happens without including `IDBKeyRange.only(indexValue)` at all. When `index` logged out, I get an `IDBIndex` object that doesn't have any methods.

Comment: It sounds like you may be running into issues with the shim. I'd try to log within the shim file you are using. `IDBKeyRange` should be implemented in `IndexedDBShim`, but `index.getAll` is not implemented yet, even in `master`. Disclosure: I'm working on the current version of `IndexedDBShim`.

Comment: Is your issue with IDBKeyRange.only() or IDBIndex.getAll()? It's not clear from the description any more.

IDBIndex.getAll() was recently added, and is only supported in newer versions of Chrome and Firefox so far. If you want to use getAll() you will need to feature-detect it and use fallback code (iterating a cursor) if not present.

Comment: Hi Joshua, u mentioned the IDBIndex.getAll() was recently added, and is only supported in newer versions of Chrome and Firefox.  Could u point me to the documenation? I could not find it anywhere. thanks!